# socket.io's integration with sails version 0.11.0

Tags: sockets, sails.js

I am working on sailsjs version 0.11.i tried a realtime connection with socket.io with sails version 0.9.3.its connecting with no problem and also socket is working well when opening to network tab socket.io/1/?t=r3625t363748372  giving status 200 OK.

but when i am working with sailsjs version 0.11.despite of updating sails.io.js.when i include this in index.html same like previously in version 0.9.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/sails.io.js"></script>
```

it is giving error of

```
localhost:3000/socket.io/1/?t=643867687647 not found (BAD request)
```

can anyone please help where i am doing wrong what can be problem with sailsjs version 0.11.0.

Comment: any error on the server side? Set log.level to debug.

Comment: no error on server side.i did same in sails version 0.9.x.and transfer my project on newer version 0.11.x.n there came a problem in socket.io connectivity.is there any bug in latest version of sailsjs regrding websocket?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your sails.io file version is not matching the server sails.js version? try taking your sails.io.js from your assets folder.